# Pagination - JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, css

Imagine that I have `1 2 3 4`pages in my table, then if I click the page `1` the number `1` will be `background: black` Then the problem is the whole pages will be black, when I executing. Please help me out of this problem. I want to change the background color of the page if what page I click. Tyia

Here's the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<div class="table-responsive" id="pagination_data"></div> 
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data();  
      function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"pagination.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#pagination_data').html(data); 
                     $(".pagination_link").css({"background":, "black"});


                }  
           })  
      }  
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page); 
           $(".pagination_link").css({"background":, "black"});
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

PHP code:

```
    <?php  
 //pagination.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "psbr");  
 $record_per_page = 6;  
 $page = '';  
 $output = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["page"]))  
 {  
      $page = $_POST["page"];  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      $page = 1;  
 }  
 $start_from = ($page - 1)*$record_per_page;  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $record_per_page";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 $output .= "  
      <div class='grid-container'>
 ";  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {  
      $output .= '  
    <div class="grid-content">
    <img src="../accounts/table/upload/'.$row['image'].'" class="grid-image">
    </div>

      ';  
 }  
 $output .= '</div> <br /><div align="right">';  
 $page_query = "SELECT * FROM accounts ORDER BY id DESC";  
 $page_result = mysqli_query($connect, $page_query);  
 $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($page_result);  
 $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$record_per_page);  
 for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++)  
 {  
      $output .= "<span class='pagination_link' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>";  
 }  
 $output .= '</div><br /><br />';  
 echo $output;  
 ?>
```

Comment: Could you just do '.pagination li.active a { background-color: black; }' in your CSS?

Comment: @IRGeekSauce what should I do? I will put that in my css?

Comment: Yes. If that is how you want all of your pagination links to look. If you have different tables, then you will need to create ids for them to narrow it down. Placing that line in your CSS should do the trick.

Comment: No, I want to be my `a` be `background-color: black` when I already click. Please help me out of this problem

Comment: Yes that it what I'm talking about. The active class means when it is clicked.

Comment: But the :active is when you hold the button or clickable button. Am I right? But I want to change the background when it's already click.

Comment: So, are you talking about the :visited selector then?

Comment: @IRGeekSauce yes! :( please help me out of this problem

Comment: It should be the same as the first comment, but with 'visited' instead of 'active.' Let me know if that doesn't work and we'll figure it out. :)

Comment: @IRGeekSauce It's working in active. But my problem is different to your answer. Imagine that I have `1 2 3 4 pages` in my table. Then If I click the `page 2` the `page 2` will be `background: black` Not by holding, not by visited. It's a button not an `a` please help me out of this problem :(

Comment: Still working on it, but I see you have $(".pagination_link").css({"background":, "black"}); when the comma needs to be removed between "background" and "black", like "background" : "black"